# magento 2.0 and 2.1 massaction compatibility issue admin back-end

Tags: magento, magento2, adminhtml, magento2.1

We have a custom written Magento 2 module that adds an action to the order overview dropdown.
Now have we ran into an issue where it would work on 2.0.x but not 2.1.x and up.

After a bit of research it is caused by Magento changing an xml node from `container` to `listingToolbar`.

Now my question is, how do we make our module compatible with both 2.0.x and 2.1.x?
Adding both; `container` and `listingToolbar` will break the massaction dropdown.

magento 2.0.x version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                      
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">                      
<container name="listing_top">                                                                                                                                      
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">                                                                                                                              
        <action name="new_action">                                                                                                                                      
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">                                                                                                                      
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                                                                                                                    
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">action_name</item>                                                                                              
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Action Name Text Here</item>                                                                    
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_module/action"/>                                                                      
                </item>                                                                                                                                                  
            </argument>                                                                                                                                                  
        </action>                                                                                                                                                        
    </massaction>                                                                                                                                                        
</container>
```

magento 2.1.x version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                      
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">                      
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">                                                                                                                                      
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">                                                                                                                              
        <action name="new_action">                                                                                                                                      
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">                                                                                                                      
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                                                                                                                    
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">action_name</item>                                                                                              
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Action Name Text Here</item>                                                                    
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_module/action"/>                                                                      
                </item>                                                                                                                                                  
            </argument>                                                                                                                                                  
        </action>                                                                                                                                                        
    </massaction>                                                                                                                                                        
</listingToolbar>
```

Comment: Me facing the same. Any suggestions please? What to do to make only one extension for both 2.0 and 2.1?

Comment: May be this can help : https://www.cminds.com/magento-layout-update-incompatibility-versions-2-0-x-2-1-x/